# in any triangle ABC, prove that the area ABNM is equal to the area ABC if N is the intersection of the circumcircle with the bisection of angle B.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

$ABC$ is a triangle, let $G$ be its circumcircle. Let $L$ be the intersection point of $AC$ and the bisection of $CBA$, and $N$ the insersection of $G$ and the bisection of $CBA$. Draw the circumcircle of $ABL$ and let its intersection with $BC$ be $M$.

Prove that:$$(area)ABNM=(area)ABC$$

I drew the figure [image]

All the black lines are of the original problem. i drew $AN$ and $NC$, and four radius from $G$: $BG$,$AG$,$NG$ and $CG$.
Let $LBA$ be $a$ so does $CBL$. Notice how $ABNM$ is cyclic so, $LBA = NCL$ and $CBL = LAN$, that makes $ACN$ an isosceles triangle and $AN = NC$. Also, the arc $AN$ can be obtained with the angle $LBA$ and $NGA$, so that makes $NGA = 2a$ and same happens with $CBN$ and $CGN$. There are more isosceles triangles but i've been trying for a while and i don't think this can be useful at all, so i was looking for a solution using what i've done or other methods. Thanks

Comment: What is $M$????

Comment: Its on the description, the title was too long and i didn't know what to do, sorry

Comment: The diagram shows the wrong bisector and the wrong side for the intersection. That is, the text of your question doesn't match the diagram.

Comment: @quasi oh sorry i didn't notice that let me fix it, the diagram ia how the question should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the intersection of $AC$ and $NM$ be $K$. Notice that $\angle LBC = \angle LBA = \angle LCN$, which gives us $$\angle AMB = \angle ALB = \angle LBC+\angle ACB = \angle LCN+\angle ACB = \angle NCB\implies AM\parallel NC$$Hence, $AMCN$ is a trapezoid $\implies S_{ANK} = S_{CMK}$. This is because
$$S_{ANK} + S_{AMK} = S_{AMN} = S_{AMC} = S_{CMK}+S_{AMN}\implies S_{ANK} =S_{CMK}$$
Hence, $$S_{ABMN} = S_{ABMK} + S_{ANK}= S_{ABMK} + S_{CMK} = S_{ABC}$$
as desired.

Comment: Where did you get that $a + ACB = ALB$?

Comment: I used Pulie's notation that $a = \angle LBC = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \angle ABC$

Comment: I'll make an edit to use angle notations to make it clearer :)

Comment: $\angle ALB + \angle BLC= 180^\circ = \angle LBC + \angle ACB + \angle BLC \implies \angle ALB = \angle LBC + \angle ACB$

Comment: Oh it's clearer now